# If $A=\{z|arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{4}\}$ and $B=\{z|arg(z-3-3i)=\frac{2\pi}{3}\}$, $z\in C$, then $n(A\cap B)$ is equal to?

Tags: complex-numbers

So the locus of $z$ will be the ray $x=y$ on the argand plane.

In the case of B, the Ray originates from $(3,3)$, which lies on $x=y$ and makes an angle $2\pi/3$ with the +ve $x$

So there is one point of intersection, so the answer should be 1. The given answer is 0. Can someone please Explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Visually there is an intersection at $(3,3)$ but $(3,3)$ is an element of $A$ only, not $B$.

Hint: check $arg(z-3-i3)$ at $z=3+i3$

Comment: Doesn’t (3,3) lie on x=y, which is the locus of B

Comment: @Aditya: How do you define the argument for $z=0$?

Comment: @Taladris you can’t.

Comment: @Aditya: then $3+3i$ cant be in $B$.

Comment: @Taladris I have sort of understood it, but I am not fully convinced. Could you please elaborate a little

Comment: @Aditya: if $z=3+3i$m, then $z-3-3i=0$. Now, $arg(z-3-3i)$ is undefined, so it cannot be equal to $2\pi/3$ and $z$ cannot be in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first locus is the ray $y=x$, in the first quadrant having a point $(3,3)$ fb it but the second locus is a ray $y-3=-\sqrt{3}(x-3)$, with $x<3$ and $y>3$ this locus leaves out the said  point so there is no common point in both the loci.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer, because you forgot to close the code on MathJax, but I don’t know what you are trying to say, so please correct it.